# Android Cardview background color with cornerradius

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a Cardview with a textview in it. Here's the xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardViewLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
            android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="PLACEHOLDER"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And I want to programmatically change the background color of the cardview. I use the following code

```
cardViewLabel!!.setCardBackgroundColor(newColor)
```

But the result of this code is like this

[image: real view]

While when I put a color in the xml file, it looks like this
[image: how it should look]

As you can see, doing it programatically does something weird with the inner TextView. And when I use this piece of code

```
cardViewLabel!!.setBackgroundColor(newColor)
```

then the color is consistent in the cardview (i.e. the textview adapts with it), but then the corner of the cardview is gone.
So how can I set the background color of a CardView programmatically while keeping the radius?

**EDIT**
The problem seems to be only when `newColor` has a transparant alpha channel. In my case, the alpha value is about 100. Solid colors do not have this problem

Comment: I copied your code and I can't reproduce your problem... `card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED)` . I have the whole card in red

Comment: what has happened to Text view? Can you please put comparable images in both cases

Comment: The only thing I did with the texview was changing its text like this:

textView!!.text = newText

Comment: @ZachBvy Color.RED works also fine with me but "newColor" has a transparant alpa channel. So the problem seems to be only present with semi transparent colors

Comment: its again correct for me when i try :         `card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.argb(120,80,200,80))`

Comment: are you sure your textview doesn't have a background?

Comment: @WouterVandenputte did you find a solution for this?